# Magento 2 - Cart empty after successful payment

Tags: magento2, cart, payment, quote, order-success-page

I have a custom payment method, after successful payment; payment page return to a controller where it updates order status and truncate current cart items like this:

```
$this->quote->load($orders->getQuoteId());

$this->quote->setReservedOrderId(null);
$this->quote->setIsActive(true);
$this->quote->removePayment();
$this->quote->save();

$this->cart->truncate();
$this->cart->saveQuote();
```

Where `$this->quote` is object of `Magento\Quote\Model\Quote`
and `$this->cart` is object of `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart`

The cart is truncating properly, but the cart summery count is still appearing on header, and when I go to view cart, it is showing empty cart with previous order total, as shown in image below

[image]

My question is, how can I fully empty my cart data after successful payment?

Comment: do you want to update summary section, right?

Comment: summery would also the part, I want to clear all data related to cart

Comment: Did you get a solution?

Comment: Not yet, will try your code. I will let you know in a while. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to use checkout session Model to clear quote data (i.e ***Magento\Checkout\Model\Session.php*** ).

Update your payment module controller code as follow.

I assume your custom payment module controller file name is **MypaymentController.php**

```
classs MypaymentController    extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    private $checkoutSession;


      public function __construct(
        ........................
        ........................
        SessionManagerInterface $checkoutSession,
        ........................
        ........................
      ){

        ........................
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        ........................
      }



    public function execute()
    {
       ........................
       $this->_checkoutSession->clearQuote();
       $this->_checkoutSession->clearStorage();
       $this->_checkoutSession->restoreQuote();
       ........................

    }    

}
```

** Note:**

If your payment module controller already injected the Checkout Session Model (i.e ***\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session***) then do not reinject Session Model,  just try to use the functions below in your controller code block.

```
$this->_checkoutSession->clearQuote();
$this->_checkoutSession->clearStorage();
$this->_checkoutSession->restoreQuote();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
I will try this, will let you know

Comment: Still facing same issue :(

Comment: if possible could you please provide full code of your payment controller?

Comment: I have shared main parts, that controller has too many stuff with a lot of "if", I have shared relevant parts

Comment: there was a code that was effecting was this `$quote->setReservedOrderId(null); $quote->setIsActive(true); $quote->removePayment();$quote->save();` so I have removed it and add your code `$this->checkoutSession->clearQuote();` now it's working fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to do following things.

1. create `sections.xml` at the following location with the code.

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\frontend\sections.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Customer:etc/sections.xsd">
    <action name="module/controller/action">
        <section name="cart"/>
        <section name="checkout-data"/>
    </action>
</config>
```

NOTE : replace `module/controller/action` with your above controller action path.

Comment: I don't get it, did you read the question? just asking, because I think you gave me answer to something else :)

Comment: @ShoaibMunir Just check answer what I give, your controller action clear the cart but summary section have issue, Magento 2 have facility to update particular section. So try the code.

Comment: sure, will try it. I will let you know. Thanks

Comment: I have tried your code, but it didn't work for me :(

Comment: ok confimm you implement code properly and run all the magento commands after change and then check into private browser mode.

Comment: Thanks for taking time answering my question. +1 for that :)

Comment: If my answer help you please upvote and accept as solution, so it help other in community.

Comment: Your code probably correct, but didn't work for me. I have accepted the answer which is worked for me. Even though I gave you +1 because you were here to help me :)

Comment: ok no worry, Thanks  :)