# Order is creating Automatically and after purchase also still product is in cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, orders, order-success-page

For few days we are facing a different issue Once we place the Order successfully it is showing the older Order id (Order id 000000960 but our current Order id 1000+) Success page.
For reference please find the attached image.
[image]

- it is happening only for few customers.

The second issue is.
After placing the order. New Order is creating automatically with different order numbers.
For reference please find the attached images.
[image]
[image]
The third issue is.
After placing the order the product is still in the cart only.
[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272931/magento-2-cart-empty-after-successful-payment  This will help you to clear cart after order-place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue is coming from the Razorpay Payment Gateway.
In Razorpay Payment Gateway they have given Webhook Option if we enable this option we are facing the above issues.
After disabling the Webhook in Razorpay Payment Gateway above issues are not occuring.